# Google Api Get nearest locations

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I want to get the List of nearest locations of by passing an address of location.
like: Los Angeles, should give me the list of all locations near to it either in json or xml format
Is there any Google api for that purpose?

Comment: what type of locations? your own or Googles?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) has lists of places near a given point. For example you can search for bookshops near Convent Garden, London, UK. A [good example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search.html) can be found in the [Google Maps Javascript API V3 Places Library documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#place_search_requests).

You can also use the Geonames.org [data dump](http://www.geonames.org/export/) and roll your own geo queries or use their [REST API](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html). Using their database you can search for various types of geographical entities (see [feature codes](http://www.geonames.org/export/codes.html)).

Most modern SQL Server deployments have some geospatial support, usually using some flavour of the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to find results nearby should you wish to download the data dump.

However, if you just want to use their public REST API you will find that they already have a [Find Nearby Toponym](http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyJSON?lat=37.774929&lng=-122.419415&username=demo) method, that takes a Feature Code and various other search parameters and returns XML or JSON.

That should enable you to [search for heliports within 50 km of San Francisco](http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyJSON?lat=37.774929&lng=-122.419415&featureCode=AIRH&&radius=50&username=demo) should you so wish!

If you would like to see this in action, in combination with Google Maps, here is something I just threw together (you'll need you own Geonames account). [In case of a zombie attack you should avoid the following cemeteries in San Francisco](http://jsfiddle.net/junto/6HHBe/embedded/result/).

Comment: @DustyRoberts I apologise in advance for my sense of humour! :-)

Answer (score 2):

'Google Geocoding API' this could help you to find the list of nearest locations by passing the address.
for reference go to this link

```
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/
```

You can use this API by passing the address. It can be also possible to find the list by passing the co-ordinates like latitude and longitude

Answer (score 0):

I think you might mean [LocalSearch API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/localsearch/start.html) which is deprecated - it's [Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) now.

Answer (score 0):

*Please refer this code below to understand properly along with API mentioning in script*
**Link from I got the code and helped me to understand.**
https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/javascript

```
function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
    var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180
    var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180
    var theta = lon1-lon2
    var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180
    var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    if (dist > 1) {
        dist = 1;
    }
    dist = Math.acos(dist)
    dist = dist * 180/Math.PI
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
    if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
    if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
    return dist
}

var data = [{
    "code": "0001",
    "lat": "1.28210155945393",
    "lng": "103.81722480263163",
    "location": "Stop 1"
}, {
    "code": "0003",
    "lat": "1.2777380589964",
    "lng": "103.83749709165197",
    "location": "Stop 2"
}, {
    "code": "0002",
    "lat": "1.27832046633393",
    "lng": "103.83762574759974",
    "location": "Stop 3"
}];

var LocNear= "";
var poslat = 1.28210155945393;
var poslng = 103.81722480263163;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // if this location is within 0.1KM of the user, add it to the list
    if (distance(poslat, poslng, data[i].lat, data[i].lng, "K") <= 0.1) {
        LocNear+= '<p>' + data[i].location + ' - ' + data[i].code + '</p>';
    }
}

$('#nearbystops').append(LocNear);
```