# Get nearest place using Sqlite database using Google places API Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to Google places API. I have seen many examples which are showing result of given radius. I am having Lang and Lat values in sqlite database Now I want to search nearest place for given address of my current location. Can any one guide me through this?

Few stackoverflow questions are regarding this and gave solution of formula.

[Query to get records based on Radius in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126830/query-to-get-records-based-on-radius-in-sqlite/9536914#9536914)
[Google Maps API, retrieving nearest places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962280/google-maps-api-retrieving-nearest-places)

Can any one give me link to demo example?

Answer (score 0):

use:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=lat,lng&radius=RADIUS&types=TYPES&sensor=false&key=KEY

Where:
lat - Your lattitude
lng - Your longitude
RADIUS  - Your radius in meters
TYPES - places types (if more then one seperate it by '|')
KEY - your api key

You can read more about it here:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not want to search using places types. I want to search using latitude and longitude which are stored in Sqlite database.

Comment: Use Geocoding, f.e. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true

Comment: I do not think this will work for me. I think you didnt understand my question.I have sqlite database which has shopname, long, lat. Now I want to search shop which is in my area like 5 km radius using my database. So I have to pass long and latitute but I have to filter it before I pass using sqlite query. I want something like this. Thanks for your help.